# MySQL query to find and replace urls that point to the root of a directory but not a subdirectory underneath it

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am having an issue from a WordPress core upgrade in which it deletes images that were in the root of my uploads directory.

In order to fix this, I'm trying to upload the images again through WordPress and have the URLs in the post content point to their new location in a subdirectory by year and month inside the uploads directory.

So what I need to do with a MySQL query is essentially:

Find: files that live in the root of "wp-content/uploads" **but don't go down another directory** such as "wp-content/uploads/2014/..."

For those results, replace "wp-content/uploads" with: "wp-content/uploads/2015/04".

I will likely be using a query like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldpath', 'newpath');
```

Is there a way to find only results that match the root of the "uploads" directory and don't go down another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find rows that match or don't match using `regexp` and update based on that conditions.

```
update wp_posts
  set post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldpath', 'newpath')
  where post_content not regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*'
```

It's a simplistic regexp but it should get the job done.

```
mysql> select 'wp-content/uploads/1.jpg' not regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*';
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'wp-content/uploads/1.jpg' not regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'wp-content/uploads/2014/1.jpg' not regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'wp-content/uploads/2014/1.jpg' not regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**updated regex to be more exclusive**
change `'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*';` to `'wp-content/uploads/[^/]*/[^"]*"';` and it will work in the fiddle you've posted below, see updated version here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d636b/1  (please take backups before executing this of course)

Comment: I tried this and got the following error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regexp 'wp-content/uploads/.*/.*'' at line 1.

For reference, I'm on MySQL version 5.5.29

Comment: ah crap. sorry. fixed. forgot to tell the query what we were regexp'ing against

Comment: Thanks. That updated query ran but affected 0 rows, which can't be right.

Comment: can you post some of your sample rows into sql fiddle? eg that exact syntax is displayed here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a05db/2 and the results are what is expected. you did change 'oldpath' and 'newpath' to the values that you want?

Comment: Thanks for that fiddle. Yes, I changed 'oldpath' and 'newpath', but doesn't hurt to check. Interesting. I think there might actually be 0 affected rows in the post_content table, but there definitely should be in the wp_postmeta table. I modified the query to run on wp_postmeta. Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/446ab/1 . It does not change the paths as expected.

Comment: Ah. the above also assumes that wp-content is the START of the string. i will adjust for you

Comment: another problem is that there was an additional `/` in another tag later in the string. i've updated the regex to be more restrictive in its choice

Comment: I see, I simplified too much in my example. Thanks for following through. The updated query worked in my local environment.